# Passing data with meta in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to pass the sec_url from the parse_sec_frame method to parse_frame and yield all three values at once. Tried it the following way without any luck and couldn't think of any other logic. Any suggestion on this? Following is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class CtSpider(CrawlSpider):
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1
    }
    name = 'ct'

    allowed_domains = ['cartoon3rbi.net']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cartoon3rbi.net/cartooncat-920.html']
    #
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="pagination"]/a[4]'), follow=True),

        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="cartoon_eps_name"]'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):

        for el in response.xpath('//div[@id="topme"]'):
            response.meta['NAME'] = el.xpath('//div[@class="block_title"]/text()').extract()

            frames = el.xpath('//div[@class="embedcode"]/iframe/@src').extract()

            for frame in frames:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=frame, callback=self.parse_frame, meta=response.meta)
                sec_link = frame.replace('1', '4')
                yield scrapy.Request(url=sec_link, callback=self.parse_sec_frame)

    def parse_sec_frame(self, response):
        response.meta['url'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="picasa"]/iframe/@src').extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(url=response.meta['url'], callback=self.parse_frame, meta=response.meta)

    def parse_frame(self, response):
        name = response.meta['NAME']
        url = response.xpath('//div[@id="picasa"]/iframe/@src').extract_first()
        sec_url = response.meta['url']
        yield {
            'Name': name,
            'Url': url,
            'sec_link': sec_url,
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you change `response.meta`? You need to create new `request` and work with `request.meta` if you want to `yield` it later. Or you can modify your code a bit:

```
   def parse_item(self, response):

        for el in response.xpath('//div[@id="topme"]'):
            NAME = el.xpath('//div[@class="block_title"]/text()').extract()

            frames = el.xpath('//div[@class="embedcode"]/iframe/@src').extract()

            for frame in frames:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=frame, callback=self.parse_frame, meta=response.meta)
                sec_link = frame.replace('1', '4')
                yield scrapy.Request(url=sec_link, callback=self.parse_sec_frame, meta={'NAME': NAME})

    def parse_sec_frame(self, response):
        url = response.xpath('//div[@id="picasa"]/iframe/@src').extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_frame, meta={'NAME': response.meta["NAME"], 'url': url})

    def parse_frame(self, response):
        name = response.meta['NAME']
        url = response.xpath('//div[@id="picasa"]/iframe/@src').extract_first()
        sec_url = response.meta['url']
        yield {
            'Name': name,
            'Url': url,
            'sec_link': sec_url,
        }
```